# I'm new to spring boot, please help me to resolve this

Tags: spring-boot

### i'm new to spring boot, please help me to resolve this authentication issue, i will put my code below

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 

( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 

\/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/
:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.5.RELEASE)

```
2020-10-31 21:09:05.196  INFO 464 --- [           main] com.test.oauth2.Oauth2Application        : Starting Oauth2Application on LAPTOP-VR6ELOC6 with PID 464 (C:\Users\personal\Desktop\delete projects\oauth2\target\classes started by personal in C:\Users\personal\Desktop\delete projects\oauth2)
2020-10-31 21:09:05.204  INFO 464 --- [           main] com.test.oauth2.Oauth2Application        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-10-31 21:09:06.903  INFO 464 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8092 (http)
2020-10-31 21:09:06.916  INFO 464 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-10-31 21:09:06.917  INFO 464 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2020-10-31 21:09:07.088  INFO 464 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-10-31 21:09:07.088  INFO 464 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1811 ms
2020-10-31 21:09:07.438  INFO 464 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: 2a478680-5ca0-4399-8049-583c4858e63c

2020-10-31 21:09:07.718  WARN 464 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter
2020-10-31 21:09:07.723  INFO 464 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-10-31 21:09:07.742  INFO 464 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-10-31 21:09:07.761 ERROR 464 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:311) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) [spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.test.oauth2.Oauth2Application.main(Oauth2Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.client.OAuth2LoginConfigurer.init(OAuth2LoginConfigurer.java:477) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.client.OAuth2LoginConfigurer.init(OAuth2LoginConfigurer.java:135) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:294) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:81) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:333) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

---

```
package com.test.oauth2;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/") 
    public String HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/restricted")
    public String restricted() {
        return "to see this text you need to be logged in !";
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.test.oauth2;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception{
        http
            .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
    }

}
```

---

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=######################
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=##########################
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
security.oauth2.client.token-name=oauth_token
security.oauth2.client.authentication-scheme=query
security.oauth2.client.client-authentication-scheme=form
security.oauth2.client.scope=profile email

security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me
security.oauth2.resource.prefer-token-info=false

server.port=8092
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>oauth2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- newly added  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- newly added  -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have clearly never worked with spring boot before

I have no idea where you got this dependency from, because it is not what you need.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

You clearly want to use oauth2 so then you need spring security.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And why you have 5 duplicates of jaxb in your pom is unknown.

Learn spring boot from the beginning from the official documentation. Then learn spring security is my advice.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. Also I changed application.property as follows.    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=